# 'LD' can't find library to link, even though 'ldconfig -v' lists the file

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, pip, ld

I'm trying to install KIWI on my RaspBerry Pi. When I attempt a

```
pip install kiwi
```

I get a linking failure, with

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/aarch64-suse-linux/10/../../../../aarch64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.6m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So I add the relevant directories to my `ld.so.conf`, and run `sudo ldconfig -v | grep python`, and the output was:

```
\ldconfig: Can't stat /libilp32: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and /etc/ld.so.conf:4)
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and /etc/ld.so.conf:2)
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libilp32: No such file or directory
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 -> libpython3.6m.so.1.0
    libpython3.8.so.1.0 -> libpython3.8.so.1.0
    libpython3.so -> libpython3.so
    libboost_python-py3.so.1.75.0 -> libboost_python3.so
    libboost_mpi_python-py3.so.1.75.0 -> libboost_mpi_python-py3.so.1.75.0
    libpytalloc-util.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.2 -> libpytalloc-util.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.2.3.1
    libpyldb-util.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.2 -> libpyldb-util.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.2.2.0
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 -> libpython2.7.so.1.0
/usr/include/python3.8: (from /etc/ld.so.conf:6)
```

note that `libpython3.6m.so` is in that list, which is what ld was complaining that it could not find. Why is the pip install of kiwi failing on ld when ld is clearly able to find the library to link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ldconfig` doesn’t configure `ld`, it configures `ld.so`, the dynamic linker/loader. `ld` is failing here because it’s looking for `libpython3.6m.so`; to provide that, you should install the relevant development package (presumably `python3-devel`).

Comment: Yep, the package was installed before the above commands were ran

Answer (score 1):

You should note that `libpython3.6m.so` is not in the output of `ldconfig`. The output mentions `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`, which is not the same.

If you don't have the development package, you can create a symlink `libpython3.6m.so` to `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`.

Besides, as has already been mentioned, the compiler and the linker don't care for `ld.so.conf`.